# How do I configure multiple domain names on my IIS server?

Tags: iis, web-hosting, domain

We have a few websites that we are running on one instance of IIS that need to be mapped for each of their domain names. For example.

```
Site A has the domain name coolness.com
Site B has the domain name 6to8Weeks.com
Site C has the domain name PhatTech.com
```

When I look at the "Web Site Identification" section of the IIS configuration window, I notice that I can specify an IP address and port, but if I click the Advanced button, I can also configure the site based on host header values as well.

How do I configure each site in IIS? Ideally I would like them to all be able to listen to port 80, so I don't have weird URLs, but I'm not sure if I do this using headers, IP addresses, both, or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

type the name into the host header field.  leave everything else as it is. job done.

You will need seperate IPs for SSL

Comment: Can I use a single "SSL" based IP address if I have multiple sites that need SSL, or will I need a new IP for each site I run under SSL?

Comment: You shouldn't need separate IPs for SSL if you use SSL certificates with Subject Alternate Names (SAN), or wildcard certificates for different subdomains.

Comment: there are big cost and trust implications with those types of certificate though so while they may be suitable for some situations, generally they are not an option

Answer (score 1):

If you have only a single IP for all three sites, you configure it using host headers. All three sites can listen on port 80 on a single IP that way.

Comment: If I have to expand this server to even more sites, is there any worry about too many sites using the same IP address?